# vertical alignment in lists

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate

I would like to align the checkboxes in my `enumerate` list below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item mbood \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item frall \hspace{0.5cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item coofp \hspace{0.5cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item ktleem    \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item sproke    \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item flube     \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item sglop \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item blick     \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item bnick \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\item strock    \hspace{0.2cm} \framebox(10,10){}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use the `\hspace{}` command, but I was wondering if there is any faster way to do this. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is something rather for a table than for an `enumerate` environment

Comment: I’d also suggest considering the `tabbing` environment, instead of `tabular`, since the former permits page breaks.  Or, would it be acceptable to have the chekboxes go *before* the words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `\parbox` around your items and `\hfill` witin:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox{.5\textwidth}{mbood \hfill \framebox(10,10){}}
\item \parbox{.5\textwidth}{frall \hfill \framebox(10,10){}}
\item \parbox{.5\textwidth}{coofp \hfill \framebox(10,10){}}
\item \parbox{.5\textwidth}{ktleem    \hfill \framebox(10,10){}}
\item \parbox{.5\textwidth}{sproke    \hfill \framebox(10,10){}}
%% ...
\end{enumerate}
```

---

> now the text looks not aligned with the number of the list anymore...

then try this inside out:

```
\parbox{.5\textwidth}{%
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item mbood\hfill \framebox(10,10){}
    \item frall\hfill \framebox(10,10){}
    \item coofp\hfill \framebox(10,10){}
    \item ktleem\hfill \framebox(10,10){}
    \item sproke\hfill \framebox(10,10){}
    %% ...
    \end{enumerate}%
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! although, now the text looks not aligned with the number of the list anymore...

Comment: nice! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RobertP. *off topic* you are aware of the [document type exsam](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf) which can do multiple choice test too?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution with using automatic numbers and alignment within a tabular environment.

Use a `longtable` environment if page breaking is an issue!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{linecounter}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{linecounter}\thelinecounter.}r}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\framebox(10,10){}}c}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{NlB}
  & mbood  & \tabularnewline
  & frall  & \tabularnewline
  & coofp  & \tabularnewline
  & ktleem     & \tabularnewline
  & sproke     & \tabularnewline
  & flube      & \tabularnewline
  & sglop &  \tabularnewline
  & blick      & \tabularnewline
  & bnick &  \tabularnewline
  & strock     & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that, all things considered, the following is a good tradeoff between simplicity and effectiveness:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\newcommand*{\robertitem}[1]{%
    \item\relax % "\relax" not really needed, but I'm neurotic!
    \makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{#1\hfill \framebox(10,10)}%
}



\begin{document}

Some text here, just for the purpose of showing where the prevailing text 
margins lie.
\begin{enumerate}
    \robertitem{Mrs. Dalloway}
    \robertitem{Said}
    \robertitem{She would buy}
    \robertitem{The flowers}
    \robertitem{Herself}
\end{enumerate}
(Please note that I~am quoting from memory.)

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output of the code]

Comment: thank you for reply! although, I get an error: it says there is missing '}' inserted, but I can't figure out why...

Comment: @RobertP.: I cannot reproduce the error.  I thought that there could be a typo, but I re-copied the code from the answer back to my editor and it compiles fine.

Comment: that's weird...I keep getting the same error, I don't know why! XD

Comment: @RobertP.: At which line of the source code does the error occur?  (TeX will report this information in the error message.)

Comment: the errors comes up at the very first `\robertitem`...

Comment: @RobertP.: Excuse me, but are you compiling *exactly* the code I’ve posted?